# hacking an INSERT query to become a mysql UPDATE query

Tags: php, mysql

I am a MySQL noob and basically hacking an insert query to become an update query instead. So I am sure it's something simple with the grammar. But what's wrong with this?

```
// Save data
$mySQLQuery = 'update `'. $fl['mysql_table']. '` SET '. $fl['mysql_query']. "' WHERE speres = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['speres']);
$rs = @mysql_query($mySQLQuery);
```

the original INSERT query (working) was

```
// Save data
$mySQLQuery = 'INSERT INTO `'. $fl['mysql_table']. '` SET '. $fl['mysql_query'];
$rs = @mysql_query($mySQLQuery);
```

The data is generated here:

```
$fl['mysql_query'] = "menrecin = '" . mysql_real_escape_string(YDFLValue($_SESSION['form']['item_17'])) . "', menrecvej = '" . mysql_real_escape_string(YDFLValue($_SESSION['form']['item_18'])) . "', menrecser = '" . mysql_real_escape_string(YDFLValue($_SESSION['form']['item_19'])) . "', menrecud = '" . mysql_real_escape_string(YDFLValue($_SESSION['form']['item_20'])) . "', menresmor = '" . mysql_real_escape_string(YDFLValue($_SESSION['form']['item_22'])) . "', menresfro = '" . mysql_real_escape_string(YDFLValue($_SESSION['form']['item_23'])) . "', menresmid = '" . mysql_real_escape_string(YDFLValue($_SESSION['form']['item_24'])) . "', menresres = '" . mysql_real_escape_string(YDFLValue($_SESSION['form']['item_25'])) . "', menrumind = '" . mysql_real_escape_string(YDFLValue($_SESSION['form']['item_28'])) . "', menrumren = '" . mysql_real_escape_string(YDFLValue($_SESSION['form']['item_29'])) . "', menrumved = '" . mysql_real_escape_string(YDFLValue($_SESSION['form']['item_30'])) . "', tekip = '" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "', tekbro = '" . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "', tektid = NOW()";
```

I have an entry with speres = 100525 in the database, so please try:

http://www.konferencer.nu/form/index.php?speres=100525

Comment: this is really hard to read, could you echo your $mySQLQuery variable and paste that instead? And your insert into statement is definitely NOT working, as it mixed UPDATE and INSERT syntax.

Comment: Remove the `@` from `mysql_query()`, echo out the variable `$mySQLQuery` to view its contents, and check the output of `mysql_error()`

Answer (score 3):

Good practices of troubleshooting dynamic SQL:

- Look at the SQL, not the code that builds the SQL.  In other words, echo out `$mySQLQuery` to see the final SQL, and most of the time you can see the error right away.
- Don't suppress errors.  [Error-checking](http://php.net/mysql_error) is helpful and necessary in any code.

It looks to me like your query ends up being:

```
update `tablename` SET ..., tektid = NOW()' WHERE speres = '...;
```

So you have a spurious quote after the `NOW()` and a missing quote at the end.

If you had checked for errors, you'd get something like this:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for 
the right syntax to use near '' WHERE speres = '...' at line 1
```

Answer (score 2):

The quoting around the start of the WHERE clause looks odd:

```
UPDATE `...some table...` SET ...some query... 'WHERE speres = ' ... some criterion ...
```

Note the single quote placement.  Maybe you want to remove the single quotes from inside the double quotes?

Answer (score 0):

you query should look like

```
$mySQLQuery = 'update'. $fl['mysql_table'].'SET'. $fl['mysql_query'].'= <some value>' ' WHERE speres = '.mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['speres']);


$rs = @mysql_query($mySQLQuery);
```